# Transforming schema of data in s3 and then import to dynamodb using a datapipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, etl, aws-glue

I have an S3 bucket storing data in DynamoDb json format. I need to crawl this data using AWS Glue, transform the column names and write back to S3. Then use a Data-Pipeline to import this data into a target DynamoDb table.

I ran the AWS Glue crawler to extract the schema of the data.
the schema consists of three columns as follows:

> col1 = {"s" : string},
>   col2 = {"s" : string},
>   key = {"s" : string},

Data in tabular form is as follows:

  `col1  col2     key
   ab    d       123
  null   r       908
   a    null     876`

So I use a pyspark dataframe and transform the names of their columns (say col1 to first and col2 to second and key to id)  using an ETL script in AWS Glue.
After that I need to write the dataframe to an S3 bucket. But because not all rows define col1 or col2 there will be null fields written in the S3 bucket.
for. e.g an entry in S3 bucket may look like:

> {"first" : null, "second":{"s":"r"}, "id":{"s":"876"}}

Now i need to transfer this data to a different DynamoDB table using a Data-Pipeline. But the Data-Pipeline cannot process null valued columns like "first":null, and hence the process fails.
Also it is not allowed to assign null columns to a random string like "0" or an empty string. The fields having null values must not be written to the table, but there corresponding defined fields must be.

Basically for the Data-Pipeline to function, the above entry in the S3 bucket must look like

> {"second":{"s":"r"}, "id":{"s":"876"}}

How to achieve this logic in an ETL script?